# how to use "or" operator with CriteriaQuery in spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Recently, I am trying use `spring-data-elasticsearch` in my project and met lots of problems. I asked a question about `not` operation yesterday but I solved by myself. And now I met another problem when trying to use `or` operator.

Here is what I want:

I want to query an object with a `code` that is not "11" and its `symbol` is "22" or its `subSymbol` is "33". I have tried many times in many ways and failed.It seems that I have no way to make it work with `CriteriaQuery`. I don't know if I described my question clearly. And in SQL, it should be written like this,

```
select from x where x.code!='11' and (x.symbol='22' or x.subSymbol='33')
```

But with `CriteriaQuery`, I always get the results if `symbol/subSymbol` value is matched and `code` condition seems missing, its SQL works like below:

```
select from x where x.code!='11' or x.symbol='22' or x.subSymbol='33'
```

Here is what I tried:

```
1.
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = new CriteriaQuery(new Criteria()
                .and("code").is("11").not()
                .or("symbol").is("22").or("subSymbol").is("33"));
2.
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = new CriteriaQuery(new Criteria()
                .and("code").is("11").not()
                .or(new Criteria("symbol").is("22").and("subSymbol").is("33")));

3.
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = new CriteriaQuery(new Criteria()
                .and("code").is("11").not()
                .and(new Criteria("symbol").is("22").or("subSymbol").is("33")));

4.
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = new CriteriaQuery(new Criteria()
                .and("code").is("11").not())
                .addCriteria(new Criteria("symbol").is("22").or("subSymbol").is("33"));


List<xx> sampleEntities =
                elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(criteriaQuery,xx.class);
```

All of the above failed.

So any solution to deal with my problem? Or I need to try `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` maybe? It is so frustrating.

Comment: How do you index those fields, do you index them as terms or you index them as a text?

Comment: Hi, Borislav, I save them with ElasticsearchRepository, and through mapping I saw they are index as text.

Comment: Can you add your mapping? full mapping of all fields

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to index your properties as Terms, because you use them as some codes(nomenclatures). You can keep the existing indexing as text if you need it in future. So I found this tutorial which looks easy to implement for your case.

> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-elasticsearch-queries

So if you add @InnerField on your fields and use query 2. but use `verbatim` suffix on fields it should work with query number 2 from your list. Your fields will be like `code.verbatim`, etc...

Also you can think of moving to `NativeSearchQueryBuilder`.